# Calculating roots with bc_math or GMP

Tags: php, math, gmp, bcmath

I'm having trouble calculating roots of rather large numbers using bc_math, example:

```
 - pow(2, 2)        // 4, power correct
 - pow(4, 0.5)      // 2, square root correct
 - bcpow(2, 2)      // 4, power correct
 - bcpow(4, 0.5)        // 1, square root INCORRECT
```

Does anybody knows how I can circumvent this? gmp_pow() also doesn't work.

Comment: For anyone searching a GMP solution, I've provided one here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21953495/603003

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a PHP programmer but looking at [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcpow.php) it says you have to pass them in as strings i.e.

```
bcpow( '4', '0.5' )
```

Does that help?

**Edit**: The [user contributed notes in the manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcpow.php#44565) confirm that it doesn't support non-integer exponents.

I did come across this [discussion of a PHP N-th root algorithm](http://www.osix.net/modules/article/?id=775) after a quick search so perhaps that's what you require.

Comment: No, it still outputs 1 instead of 2.

Comment: Yes, bcsqrt works but I also need to find roots with other indexes such as 3, 5 and so on.

Comment: @eyze: Yes, I know. I just wanted to check that it was working.

Comment: The last link you provided is useful however it wrongly returns 1.5 for the square root of 2, is there any more precise workarround?